# Applying matrix multiplication in chain to several sets of values

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Mathematically, I'm trying to calculate **x**^T **A** **x**, where **x** is an n-dimensional coordinate and **A** a n-dimensional square matrix. However, I'd like to efficiently calculate this for a set of coordinates. For example, in two dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.column_stack([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,0]])
A = np.array([[1,0],[0,2]])

print(x[0] @ A @ x[0])  # works
# How can I get efficiently an array of x[i] @ A @ x[i]?
y = [x[i] @ A @ x[i] for i in range(x.shape[0])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> (x @ A @ x.T).diagonal()
array([ 73, 102, 137, 178,  25])
```

Or maybe:

```
>>> (x @ A * x).sum(axis=1)
array([ 73, 102, 137, 178,  25])
```

Good [einsum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) suggestion from [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78195369/applying-matrix-multiplication-in-chain-to-several-sets-of-values/78195395?noredirect=1#comment137857495_78195395) in comments:

```
>>> np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i', x, A, x)
array([ 73, 102, 137, 178,  25])
```

Comment: Yes, that looks good. Does this waste CPU computing unnecessary values, however?

Comment: Maybe - added an alternative which avoids that.

Comment: Oh, that second one was twice as fast for my testcase. Thanks!

Comment: slightly better time with `np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->i',x,A,x)`